# LDAP query, geto all user of a group

Tags: active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2019

Goodmorning,
i have neer worked with LDAP filter.
Basically i'm trying to get all users that are member of a group

my AD is composed by 1 domain, a series of Organization Unit with inside all users.
i have added some of this users, to a group (NameOfGroups)

can u pls help me?
thanks you

i tried to compose this query, but this return an empty results.

```
(&(&(|(&(objectCategory=person)(objectSid=*)(!samAccountType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.804:=3))(&(objectCategory=person)(!objectSid=*))(&(objectCategory=group)(groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.804:=14)))(objectCategory=group)(objectClass=group)(member=NameOfGroups)))
```

Comment: How did you end up with this query? In particular the large `(|..)` branch? What is it supposed to match?

Comment: i have used the query creatore option in active directory

Comment: i solved it (&(objectClass=user)(memberOf=CN=xxxx,CN=xx,DC="XXX",DC="xx")